# Error al conectar con la base de datos usando PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Estoy tratando de conectar mi web con una base de datos sql-server (uso Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio).

He entrado en la base de datos usando SQL Server Authentication mediante usuario y contraseña que ya tenía creados. Para exponer mi problema diremos las credenciales son: Login: **usuario** / Password: **1234** y la base de datos se llama **prueba**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para hacer un test de la conexión he usado el siguiente código:

```
<?php 
    $servername = 'DESKTOP-FHALK16\SQLEXPRESS';
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"prueba", "UID"=>"usuario", "PWD"=>"1234", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
    $conn_sis = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);

    if($conn_sis){
        echo "Hay conexión!!!";
    }else{
        echo "Fallo en la conexion";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

Al ejecutar el código me sale que hay conexión pero al hacer la conexión con PDO no se conecta.
Código PDO:

```
$base = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = DESKTOP-FHALK16\SQLEXPRESS;Database=prueba", 'usuario', '1234');
$base ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$base -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

try{
    $query = "SELECT ID_USUARIO FROM USUARIOS";
    $resultado = $base -> prepare($query);
    $resultado->execute(array());

    while($row = $resultado -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
        echo $row['ID_USUARIO'];
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Linea de error: " . $e->getLine();
}
```

Tengo los drivers necesarios instalados tal y como muestra la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado a quitar los espacios en blanco alrededor del `=` en la cadena de conexión? (`sqlsrv:server=DESKTOP`en lugar de `sqlsrv:server = DESKTOP`)

Comment: lo acabo de probar pero sigue sin funcionar, no sé que puede estar fallando

Comment: Podrías atrapar el error que te devuelve y compartirlo?

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el siguiente codigo

```
$base = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = DESKTOP-FHALK16\SQLEXPRESS;Database=prueba", 'usuario', '1234');
```

por este

```
$base = new PDO("sqlsrv:host=DESKTOP-FHALK16\SQLEXPRESS;dbname=prueba", 'usuario', '1234');
```

espero te funcione

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes todos los drivers instalados correctamente e indicas las credenciales correctas, debería funcionar del siguiente modo:

```
function conectar()
{

 /* $serverName = "sqlserver.example.com"; //remoto */
    $serverName = "(local)\sqlexpress"; //local   

    $database = "myDbName";
    $user = 'sqlserver_username';
    $pwd = 'password';
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$database", $user, $pwd,
                array(
                       //PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                         PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                         PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false //Importante
                     )
                 );
    return $conn; 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
       die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
       return null;
     }
}
```

---

Para más detalles: [Microsoft, Example Application (PDO_SQLSRV Driver)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver)

Comment: He probado de usar esta función con mis datos y me da el siguiente error: ´Error connecting to SQL Server: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The given attribute is only supported on the PDOStatement object.´

Comment: @gmarsi prueba quitando esta línea `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,` en el array de opciones. O bien intenta así, sin el array de opciones: `$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$database", $user, $pwd);`